# Get out of memory error when fetch 3000 record of data

Tags: mysql, yii

i'm trying to index a table that contains more than 3000 record with zend lucene in console command

here is my code

```
public function run($args) {
    set_time_limit(0);      
    Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
    require_once 'Zend/Search/Lucene.php';

    Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
    Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
            new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive ()
    );

    $searchPath = Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/search';
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create($searchPath);
    /*
     * fecth data to index
     */ 
    $sql = 'select id, title, content, succinct, create_time from `news` where status="published"';
    $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $result = $query->queryAll();

    foreach ($result as $data) {
        $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title',
            CHtml::encode($data['title']), 'UTF-8')
        );
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('succinct',
                strip_tags($data['succinct']), 'UTF-8')
        );          
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('content',
                strip_tags($data['content']), 'UTF-8')
        );
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('newsId',
                $data['id'], 'UTF-8')
        );
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('create_time',
                $data['create_time'], 'UTF-8')
        );
        $index->addDocument($doc);          
    }
    $index->commit();
    $index->optimize(); 
}

}
```

but i get this error

> Out of memory (Needed 228480 bytes)
>   exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2008 MySQL client ran out of memory. The SQL statement executed was: select id, title, content, succinct, create_time from `news` where status="published"' in /home/user/public_html/v2/lib/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:528

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similiar error a while ago.
I could fix it by increasing the database cache.
You can also try increasing the amount of memmory your php interpreter gets during execution (client ran out of memmory).
It may help you, too.

Comment: could you explain more  i have set memory_limit to 256MB but it's not helpful

Comment: That was my only guess. I'm sorry!